# Use multiple aws outbound adaptor in a single integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-aws

***strong text***I want to use 2 aws outbound adaptor in a single integration flow. One is outbound S3 adaptor and one outbound SQS adaptor. I have to move file from smb share to S3 bucket then use the transformer and then use the SQS adaptor to send transformed message to SQS queue. I can achieve this with 2 integration flow but I want to achieve this with only one integration flow. If I add both outbound adaptor part of one flow only one of them is working

Answer (score 1):

That’s true, two Outbound channel Adapters can’t work one after another. Just because one-way component doesn’t return anything to send as a payload into the output channel.

You might need to make yourself familiar with the `publish-subscribe` pattern: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/PublishSubscribeChannel.html.

In the `IntegrationFlow` you just need to configure a `publishSubscribeChannel` with two subscribers as sub-flows for your different Channel Adapters.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#java-dsl-subflows

**UPDATE**

Since you already have an `.enrichHeaders(h->h.header("bucketName”,”mybucket”))` before `publishSubscribeChannel()`, it is a fact that this one is going to be available for both subscribers downstream.

To make access into it from the `s3MessageHandler`, you must configure it like this:

```
public MessageHandler s3MessageHandler() {
    S3MessageHandler handler = new S3MessageHandler(amazonS3, 
             new FunctionExpression<>(m -> m.getHeaders().get(”mybucket”)));
    return handler;
}
```

To make access to that header for your next SQS subscriber part, you need to change your `transform()` method signature to accept the whole `Message<>`, so you get access to headers again for building some custom message for SQS.

Comment: Well, the best way is to store that information in headers before sending to the `publishSubscribeChannel`. So, S3 Outbound Channel adapter would use them to store remote file and SQS channel adapter would reuse the same information for its goals.

Comment: Any chances to share what you have so far? What is bad in having `bucketExpression` and `keyExpression` configured on the `S3MessageHandler` ?

Comment: Please, edit your question. That code snippet is not readable in the comments.

Comment: ??? I said: *edit your question*, not *my answer*. Please, be careful and respectful. You also need to keep in mind that we have our job to do as well. So, our time helping here is valuable. Thanks for understanding. Please, post as a *code* also, not a picture. It will be helpful in copy/pasting and editing.

Comment: No, it's still unreadable. What is wrong with editing your own question? Where is an S3 channel adapter? What does your `transform(m)` do? A lot of questions because of your won code. I'm not sure how to help you from here... Sorry

Comment: In what place? Expression or your `transform()`? How does exception look?

Comment: Try this, please: `new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> m.getHeaders().get(”mybucket”))`

Comment: Yes, you can get all of that info in your transformer, as long as arg type is `Message<?>`. See headers in debug mode. And also I guess that your `payload` is `File`, so you can simply get access its name.

Comment: You can't do `.setHeader("id", generate())`. Essentially you can't modify this header at all: it is generated by the Framework.

Comment: Try `.transform(Message.class, m -> transform(m))` instead.

Comment: You know, it's getting too far from the original request in the SO topic. Let's consider to stop the discussion here! Feel free to raise you questions though!